# How can I use a specific mirror server in Fedora?

Tags: dnf, fedora-23

I'm using fedora 23 and I want to change the default settings in `dnf` in order to use a specific server mirror from [here](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/mirrormanager/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple options, you can hard code  it (`/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo`) or using `fastmirror`.

In order to use `fastmirror` you must first activate it:

in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` add `fastestmirror=true`
then using this command `dnf config-manager --add-repo` add the mirror you want to use, you can add multiple mirrors and the fastest one will be used.

Example:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo http://ftp.byfly.by/pub/fedoraproject.org/linux/releases/23/Everything/x86_64/os/
```

You must use the path `/linux/releases/23/Everything/x86_64/os/` for fedora 23 releases and for fedora 23 updates `/linux/updates/23/x86_64/` otherwise will not work.

Comment: fastestmirror is unfortunately named; it has nothing to do with throughput and only ping time, and will generally cause trouble.

https://twitter.com/KWF/status/1585319975438340097

https://twitter.com/carlwgeorge/status/1585442730162913282

Answer (score -2):

To change Fedora Mirror and some setting to reach highest speed do this

Edit the dnf configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
```

Add the following lines:

```
deltarpm=false
keepcache=true
ip_resolve=4
```

It depends on your own that you like DeltaRPM or not (true or false). Google it to find what exactly it does.

In the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory there are files that need a small edit.
The main file is `fedora-updates.repo`

Add `country=us` (use your own country code) to the end of all of the "`metalink`" lines for the fedora repo files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`

It's better to use de, nl or any european country that have the strong, fast servers. Bandwith capacity matters and not ping.

Comment: sorry for bumping an old topic but as it come up in google searches, I think its better to complete this with what I have done and got result