# Fedora: dnf keeps showing "European Southern Observatory RPM repository" message

Tags: fedora, dnf

Whenever I use `sudo dnf` to install a package on Fedora 36, this message always appears:

```
European Southern Observatory RPM repository fo 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:06    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'esorepo':
  - Curl error (9): Access denied to remote resource for ftp://ftp.eso.org/pub/dfs/pipelines/repositories/stable/fedora/36/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Server denied you to change to the given directory]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'esorepo': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Ignoring repositories: esorepo
```

After, the terminal output seems normal and shows output relevant to the package I am about to install, but this previous message is annoying. Any suggestions?

Comment: **Welcome to Superuser! You might want to start by taking the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and reading [How do I ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).** Please include in your question what research you've done, what exact steps you've taken to resolve the issue by yourself and where exactly you got stuck. Please include as much information as possible to increase the chances of getting an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a specific mirror server in Fedora?](https://superuser.com/questions/1035780/how-can-i-use-a-specific-mirror-server-in-fedora)